# Aurelia child router does not go through main router pipeline

Tags: aurelia

The main router's pipeline of my application redirects to login page if a user is not logged in.

It works fine for most pages, but when said page holds itself a child router, the logic does not seem to hit the main router's pipeline, preventing redirection (as well as not rendering the page).

main router:

```
configureRouter (rc: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    this.router = router;

    rc.addAuthorizeStep(this.requireAuth);

    const auth = { authenticated: true, needsCurrentOrg: true };

    const loginRoute = {
      route: 'login/:token?',
      name: 'login',
      moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('views/login/login'),
    };

    rc.map([
      {
        route: [ROOT_PAGE, DASHBOARD_PAGE],
        name: DASHBOARD_PAGE,
        moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('views/dashboard/dashboard'),
        settings: auth
      },
      {
        route: CREDENTIALS_PAGE,
        name: CREDENTIALS_PAGE,
        moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('views/credentials/credentials-root'),
        settings: auth
      })]
}
```

credentials router:

```
configureRouter (rc: RouterConfiguration) {
    rc.map([
      {
        route: '',
        name: 'credentials-list',
        moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./credentials-grid'),
      }
    ]);
  }
```

So if I hit `/#/dashboard` without being logged in, I get redirected to `/login`, but nothing happens if I hit `/#/credentials`: blank page, no redirection. I put a `debugger` in the `requireAuth` middle-ware code, and in the first case it does step in, in the second case it does not go through

Answer (score 1):

Finally identified the issue, for some reasons it looks like the `LoadRouteStep` pipeline step (internal to the `AppRouter`) tried to load the ViewModel of the subrouter target.

Since this ViewModel had some code in the constructor, that code was failing, creating an error and stopping the pipeline - never reaching the redirection.

The fix was to move that constructor code into an `activate` function for the ViewModel.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that you are using empty route for credential list. Can you check that?